# Export Datatable to Excel without taking into consideration HTML tags

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

There are lots of methods in order to export datatable to Excel file.

But when a column includes HTML tags, the structure of Excel is corrupted, it seems like HTML document.

How can I prevent exporting datatable to excel without taking into consideration HTML tags?

Code I use is below:

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table, string name)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            context.Response.Write(column.ColumnName + ",");
        }
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
            }
            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name + ".xls");
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code at least what you tried..

Comment: I have shared code which I form excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample)

```
private void CreateExcel(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);                

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            }
        }
```